# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'elasticsearch'

Tags: elasticsearch, python-3.7

I am new to Python. MAC user, I have Python 3.7 and I have installed Elasticsearch via `pip3 install elasticsearch`. I do not have any other file named Elasticsearch and I tried to fix the PYTHONPATH as suggested on other posts. I also tried to uninstall and re-install Elasticsearch again. Same error. When I run...

```
import logging
import elasticsearch


def gotoelk():
    _es = None
    _es = Elasticsearch([{'host':'Internal IP of my Elasticsearch', 'port': 9200}])
    if _es.ping():
        print('Connected')
    else:
        print('NOT connected')
    return _es
if __name__ == '__main__':
  logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)
gotoelk()
```

I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/username/Desktop/MBAPI/ELK_connect_test.py", line 3, in <module>
        import elasticsearch

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'elasticsearch'
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: How are you running your file?  Are you using `python3 ELK_connect_test.py`?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I'm trying to run it by simply using `python3 file_name.py`.